# populating one field value based on another field value

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

I have a feature class in a personal geodatabase with 2 fields. They both have domains set up to ease the editing process for my users. If my WaterType field is set as "Not Irrigated" (or code 4) then I need my IrrigType to be set as "Not Irrigated" (code 0). I'm not sure if I want to use the description or the code for the domains.

I would also like to set this up so that it runs automatically...so that I don't need to calculate field and run the Python script every time.

Any suggestions? I tried the following code to no avail:

```
def calIrrigType(WaterType, IrrigType):
  if WaterType=='Not Irrigated':
    return 0
 else:
  return IrrigType
```

Comment: Check the indentations in the if/else statements--they appear unequal.

Comment: I may have an old script that does something similar ill have to see if I can find it and ill post it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Aaron's comment, once the code is working, I would suggest the following to automatically run the data update:

1. create a model using the Calculate Field tool
2. export it out to python script
3. call the script to run from a .bat file
4. schedule the .bat to run from e.g. Windows scheduler.

Comment: +1 but you should normally be able to call the *.py to run direct from the Windows Scheduler without wrapping it in a *.bat.

Comment: ok, good to know!